# Cmd tree to Json

Tags: windows, json, command-line, tree

I have a text file with a folder structure:

```
+---A Momentary Lapse of Reason
+---A Saucerful of Secrets
+---Animals
+---Atom Heart Mother
+---Delicate Sound Of Thunder
+---Echoes- The Best of Pink Floyd
|   +---Echoes- The Best of Pink Floyd Disc 1
|   \---Echoes- The Best of Pink Floyd Disc 2
+---Is There Anybody out There- The Wall- Live 1980-1981 Disc 1
+---Is There Anybody out There- The Wall- Live 1980-1981 Disc 2
\---Works
```

I received it from `windows CMD` using the `tree` command.
I wanted to know if there is a simple way to convert this structure into `json`?

For something like this it isn't too hard to do it manually, but I need to do it for a `12TB` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I'm not so familiar with JSON. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194287/2098699) thread and wrote a batch script. Please let me know, if I can something improve.

```
@echo off &setlocal
if "%~1"=="" (set "root=.") else set "root=%~1"
set "pre0=                                    "

pushd %root%
echo(data = [
call:dirtree "%CD%" "1" "1"
popd
echo(];
goto:eof

:dirtree
setlocal
call set "pre=%%pre0:~-%~2%%
set /a ccount=%~3
set /a tcount=%~2+2
set /a dcount=0
for /d %%i in (*) do set /a dcount+=1
echo( %pre%{
echo(  %pre%"type": "folder",
echo(  %pre%"name": "%~nx1",
set "fpath=%~f1"
set "fpath=%fpath:\=/%"
echo(  %pre%"path": "%fpath%",
echo(  %pre%"childno": %ccount%,
if %dcount% equ 0 echo(  %pre%"subchilds": %dcount%
if %dcount% gtr 0 (
    echo(  %pre%"subchilds": %dcount%,
    echo(  %pre%"children": [
    for /d %%i in (*) do (
        for /f %%j in ('call echo "%%dcount%%"') do (
            cd "%%i"
            call:dirtree "%%i" "%tcount%" "%%j"
            cd ..
        )
        set /a dcount-=1
    )
    echo(  %pre%]
)
if %ccount% equ 1 (echo  %pre%}) else echo( %pre%},
endlocal
goto:eof
```

Usage: `tree2json [startfolder] [>file.txt]`

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! All I had to do is add `"` to all of the names (IE `echo(  %pre%type: "folder",` = `echo(  %pre%"type": "folder",`) and I need to run a "replace `\` with `/`. Thank you so much :D

Comment: "replace" `\ ` with `/` **

Comment: When you do `"%~f1"` it gives the path to the folder. The path has `\ `'s and apparently `Json` doesn't like it. :P

Comment: OK, I can change this and add the missing double quotes (need some time, I'm on the tablet now) .... :)