# how to read json file's name from the android app?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a bunch of folders which are categorised by the name of the poets and inside those folders are JSON files which are named by the title of the poem.
So how can i browse those files from the app.
the number of writers and the number of poems are too many that i can not tell how many poems are there. i want to first call all the poets name ant then the titles.

I can't think of any way to have tried this.

Collection Structure

All poems can be found in the collection directory in the corresponding author's sub-directory.

```
collection
├── William Cowper
│   └── Light Shining out of Darkness.json
└── William Ernest Henley
    └── Invictus.json
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194287/convert-a-directory-structure-in-the-filesystem-to-json-with-node-js)

Comment: thank you that was helpful but I want some implementation for a newbie i don't know node.js

Answer (score 0):

```
int Index = 0;  // Global
String[] FileDir; // Global 

// Start onCreate or some function 
File currentDir = new File(""); // collection directory as parameter
DisplayFile(currentDir);


public static void DisplayFile(File currentDir)
{
    try {

        File[] files = currentDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {

            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                //System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                DisplayFile(file);

            } else {
                if(file.getCanonicalFile().toString().contains(".json"))
                FileDir[Index] = file.getCanonicalPath();
                Index++;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```