# Node.js convert directory tree to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

**What is expected?:**
I would like to convert the below listed directory structure
into a single JSON file.
The directory structure contains JSON files
that are supposed to be included in
the output file as well.

**Limitations:**
Node.js

**Questions:**
What would be a good/efficient
way to generate the desired output,
using Node.js + Modules?
Logically, what would be the
necessary steps?

**Directory structure:**

```
CMS/
├── en/
|   ├──brand_one/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_two/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_three/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
├── de/
|   ├──brand_one/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_two/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_three/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
├── fr/
|   ├──brand_one/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_two/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_three/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
├── es/
|   ├──brand_one/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_two/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json
|   ├──brand_three/
|   |  ├──footer.json
|   |  ├──header.json

[...]
```

**Desired output:**

```
// content.json

{
  "en":[
    {
      "brand_one":{
        "footer":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        },
        "header":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        }
      },
      "brand_two":{
        "footer":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        },
        "header":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        }
      },
      "brand_three":{
        "footer":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        },
        "header":{
          "val": "value",
          [...]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Check it out here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194287/convert-a-directory-structure-in-the-filesystem-to-json-with-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to convert a directory to an object, with a property for each dir / file.

This would then be called recursively to walk the entire tree, in this case using the [fs/promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) functions.

```
const fs = require('fs/promises'); 
const path = require('path');

async function walkDir(dir, result = {}) {
    let list = await fs.readdir(dir);
    for(let item of list) {
        const itemPath = path.join(dir, item);
        let stats = await fs.stat(itemPath)
        if (await stats.isDirectory()) {
            result[item] = {};
            await walkDir(itemPath, result[item]);
        } else {
            const fileName = path.basename(item, path.extname(item));
            result[fileName] = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(itemPath, { encoding: 'utf-8'}));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

async function testWalkDir() {
    let result = await walkDir('./CMS')
    console.log("Result:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

testWalkDir();
```

Assuming each file looks like

```
{
  "some_key": "some_val"
}
```

I get a result that looks like so:

```json
{
  "en": {
    "brand_one": {
      "footer": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      },
      "header": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      }
    },
    "brand_three": {
      "footer": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      },
      "header": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      }
    },
    "brand_two": {
      "footer": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      },
      "header": {
        "some_key": "some_val"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You may use npm package tree-parser.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-parser

Answer (score 1):

You can try this module:

[**npm dree**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dree#install)

Example code:

```js
const dree = require('dree');

const options = {
    stat: false,
    normalize: true,
    followLinks: true,
    size: true,
    hash: true,
    depth: 5,
    exclude: /dir_to_exclude/,
    extensions: [ 'txt', 'jpg' ]
};

const tree = dree.scan('./folder', options);
```

There are lots of custom options, a result could be this:

```json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample",
  "relativePath": ".",
  "type": "directory",
  "size": "1.81 MB",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend",
      "relativePath": "backend",
      "type": "directory",
      "size": "1.79 MB",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "firebase.json",
          "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/firebase.json",
          "relativePath": "backend/firebase.json",
          "type": "file",
          "extension": "json",
          "size": "29 B"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "server",
          "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/server",
          "relativePath": "backend/server",
          "type": "directory",
          "size": "1.79 MB",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "server.js",
              "path": "D:/Github/dree/test/sample/backend/server/server.js",
              "relativePath": "backend/server/server.js",
              "type": "file",
              "extension": "js",
              "size": "1.81 MB"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Even a string could be returned, like this:

```json
sample
 └─> backend
     ├── firebase.json
     ├── hello.txt
     └─> server
         └── server.js
```